# Searching for a type of geometric flow in Lorentzian geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(N,g)$ be a globally hyperbolic Lorentzian manifold. Given any smooth hypersurface $\Sigma$ in $(N,g)$ we define $\|\Sigma\|= \sup_{p \in N,X \in T_p\Sigma} |h(X,X)|$ where $h$ is the second fundamental form of $\Sigma$.

I wonder if given any smooth timelike hypersurface $\Sigma_0 \subset N$ one can construct a canonical foliation $\{\Sigma_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ with the following properties:

1. $\{\Sigma_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a smooth foliation by **timelike** hypersurfaces.
2. Given each $t>0$, there holds: $\|\Sigma_t\|<\|\Sigma_0\|$.
3. $\{\Sigma_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is complete in the sense that there is no hypersurface $Y\subset N$ such that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\Sigma_t=Y$ (with respect to some standard topology).

If the answer is in general no, can one impose some extra soft additional assumptions on $(N,g)$ to make the existence of such a foliation always possible?

Comment: By "timelike hypersurface", do you mean that the unit normal is a time-like vector? Also, in condition 1, what is $\Sigma_t$ a foliation of? $N$?

Comment: Also, condition 2 is awfully strong: if $\Sigma_0$ is totally geodesic, then $\|\Sigma_0\| = 0$ and clearly you cannot have any foliation with the strict inequality as denoted.

Comment: By timelike I mean that the normal unit vector is spacelike. Also I agree with your comment on the condition 2, but all I want is to first define a kind of “norm” or C^2 energy for these hypersurfaces and require that the energy pf the subsequent leaves are smaller than the initial energy

Comment: Obviously the choice of energy that I defined was wrong because it could be zero, but maybe you can modify the enrgy to something else